# Autocomplete materialize fechando

Tags: php, jquery, json, materialize, autocompletar

Amigos alguém sabe como resolver o seguinte problema, o autocomplete do materialize, não mostra ao completar o lenght, mas ao clicar novamente no input ele abre e fecha rapidamente sem selecionar nada, ele está sendo  populado com os dados, estou usando a versão 1.0.0 do materialize e o jquery 3.3.1. Alguma ideia de como resolver? Obrigado.

```
$(document).on('input', 'input.autocomplete', function() {
    let im = $(this).val();
    var base_url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>';
    var url = "<?php echo site_url('/pesquisa/imobiliarias')?>";
    $.post(url, {
        im: im
    }, function(suggestions) {
        var Array = JSON.parse(suggestions);
        var List = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
            List[Array[i].im] = Array[i].flag;
        }
        $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
            data: List,
            limit: 20,
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
});
```

No controller:

```
function imobiliarias(){
    $im = $this->input->post('im');
    echo json_encode($this->Model_pesquisa->imob($im));
}
```

No Model:

```
function imob($im) {
    $this->db->select('im');
    $this->db->like('im', $im);
    $this->db->from('entrega');
    $this->db->group_by('im');
    $this->db->order_by('im', 'asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() >= 1) {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

No console.log

```
{"Cia do imóvel ": undefined, Roca Imóveis: undefined}
```

Comment: Observei que não tem o arquivo php, seria imobiliarias.php, Poderia colocar o exemplo do JSON que vc está retornando??

Comment: Eu editei com os retornos

Comment: Ele popula o auto complete só não faço idéia do pq ele fecha...

Comment: O console.log está antes do 'var Array = JSON.parse(suggestions);' ?? coloca o console.log(suggestions) antes dele e posta o result dele.

Comment: [{"im":"Cia do im\u00f3vel "},{"im":"Roca Im\u00f3veis"}]   este é o antes do json.parse

Comment: Depois das informações que vc repassou, consegui reproduzir e não teve essa falha!!

Comment: Ja tentei de outras formas e da no mesmo, na versão 0.100 ele funciona normal mas nesta não, não posso fazer o downgrade da versão do materialize tem muita coisa q não funciona nesta versão